# Only the first Row shows on query

Tags: java, database, h2

When I run the following code only values from the first row show

package Database.H2;

```
package Database.H2;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateTable {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test", "sa", "");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("NAME"));

            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 5 rows in the database that I entered manually. How can I get all the rows to display?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the cause:

```
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your loop `rs.next()`, you called `conn.close`, so it prints the 1st row correctly. Bring the `conn.close` outside your loop.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. That helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on, instead of importing all files separately `sql.Connection`, `sql.DriverManager`, `sql.ResultSet`, `sql.SQLException` and `sql.Statement`. Just import one file like this; `import java.sql.*;`